# how i add a img that a user sent in a discord.py embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm making a suggestion discord bot, and I'd like to know if there's how I can add an image that the user posted on embed

something like

`embed.set_image(url=image_url)`

the **image_url** would be the image the user added to the message.

```py
suggestion_channel_id = 925568558241550393
color = 0x3498db

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    suggestionData = '{}'.format(message.content).replace('?sugestão','')
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('?sugestão'):
        embed=discord.Embed(title ='Nova sugestão!')
        embed.add_field(name='Vote Abaixo!', value=suggestionData, inline=True)
        channel=bot.get_channel(suggestion_channel_id)
        embed.color=color
        embed.set_footer(text='Sugestão por ' + message.author.name, icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
        up_emoji = '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}'
        down_emoji = '\N{THUMBS DOWN SIGN}'
        msg = await channel.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction(up_emoji)
        await msg.add_reaction(down_emoji)
        await message.channel.send('Sua sugestão foi enviada!' + '** ' + message.author.name + ' ' + ' **')


token = config("token")
bot.run(token)
```

Comment: There's 2 ways, you could either require an image argument and have your users post a link to the image, or you could make the users attach an image to the message and get it via `message.attachments`.

Comment: ok the attach is what i want but how do i set the image now?
bcause `embed.set_image(url= message.attachments)` is wrong

Comment: View the answer of @Ratery below for a solution, `message.attachments` is a list so you wanna get the first image in that list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`message.attachments`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.attachments) to get a list of message attachments:

```py
@bot.command()
async def send_image(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Your attached image")
    if len(message.attachments):
        embed.set_image(url=ctx.message.attachments[0].url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: not sure how i can apply it there, i edited my post please take a look and sorry if it looks confused